# In jquery, when i click close link and outside the div my toggle class not getting hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing toggle class to hide and show, toggle class is working fine, but when i click that "Close" link and outside the div the current displaying div was not getting hide, i am new to jquery. help me if any one know this answer, i have attacted a code below.

Html code

```
<div class="NoViews">
        <img src="~/Content/Theme/images/fav.png" alt="">
        <p>Shortlist</p>
        <span>1</span>
    <div class="shortlistProperty">
        <div class="shortlistHeader">
             <h5>Shortlisted properties (1)
                 <p class="flRight"><a class="closeShortlist" href="#">Close</a></p>
             </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="shortlistBody">
             Div content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".shortlistProperty").hide();
            $(".mySearchProperty").hide();                
            $(".NoViews").click(function () {
                $('.shortlistProperty').toggle();
                $('.mySearchProperty').hide();
            });
            $(".closeShortlist").click(function () {
                $('.shortlistProperty').toggle();
                $('.shortlistProperty').toggle(false);
            });
            $(".searchView").click(function () {
                $('.mySearchProperty').toggle();
                $('.shortlistProperty').hide();
            });
            $(".closemySearch").click(function () {
                $('.mySearchProperty').toggle();
                $('.mySearchProperty').toggle(false);
            });
        });
```

In this, i want when i click that close link my current div have to get hides and when i click out side the current div have to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop the event bubble. Check the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".shortlistProperty").hide();
        $(".mySearchProperty").hide();
        $(".NoViews").click(function (e) {
            $('.shortlistProperty').toggle();
            $('.mySearchProperty').hide();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('.shortlistProperty').click(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(".closeShortlist").click(function (e) {
            $('.shortlistProperty').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(".searchView").click(function (e) {
            $('.mySearchProperty').toggle();
            $('.shortlistProperty').hide();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $(".closemySearch").click(function (e) {
            $('.mySearchProperty').toggle();
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
        $('body').click(function (e) {
            $('.shortlistProperty').hide();
        });
    });
```

Comment: sorry brother, if i have any mistake. i am now to jquery

Comment: Thanks close button was working, but when i click outside the div current showing div was not getting hide, is there any way to solve this....

Comment: Thanks brother, i got solution from your answer and also i learn new from you. thank you once again